# Integral form of impulse signals, when the limits are not infinite

Tags: integration

I am a current sophomore in a signals course and am having issues with this problem:

$$\int_1^2 (t^2+1)(t) \,dt$$

I understand that when $t=0$, $\delta = \infty$,  otherwise $\delta =0$.

Would this not mean that this is equal to $0$?

Comment: Well, it is NOT an integral.  But with $f(t)=t^2+1$ and $p_{12}(t)=1$ for $1<t<2$ and $0$ otherwise,  the value of the functional $\langle \delta, f p_{12}\rangle $ is indeed $0$.